# XPath Need help getting part of href value preceding specific characters

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get the following information extracted out of a link using XPath, for example:

I have `<a href="index.cfm?ag_num=470">LINK TEXT HERE</a>`

I would like to select the href value of the link but only anything following **ag_num=**

So I would end up with **470** for the link above. Any ideas are truly appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below `XPath` expression to get required value:

```
substring-after(//a/@href, "ag_num=")
```